# wait until button is pressed

Tags: python, pygtk

I basically have questions being asked in a for loop and I'm trying to make each question wait for a response (aka a button to be clicked) before showing the next question..
I was wondering how I can get this done because the way I have it setup now is that each question will appear one after the other regardless of the response...

Answer (score 2):

Don't put it in a `for` loop, you need to show the next question as a reaction to an event.

I haven't worked with pygtk, but to make yourself an idea, if you had something like this:

```
for question in questions:
    some_text_pane.set_text(question)
    #wait until button pressed
```

you should have something like that:

```
question_pool = iter(questions)
def next_question(evt):
    question = next(question_pool)
    some_text_pane.set_text(question)

some_button.set_event_handler(next_question)
```

of course I don't know the GTK API, so don't take the method names literally.

Comment: In gtk `some_button.set_event_handler(callback)` would be `some_button.connect('clicked', callback)` and `next_question(evt)` would be `next_question(button)`. Anyway, the explanation is completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a `for` loop won't let the `gtk` main loop do it's jobs and call the callback methods for the events you expect and your application will be unresponsive.

One way to do what you need is use a [`gtk.Assistant`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkassistant.html) with one question per page in the assistant object and, possible, one last page with a summary of the results to the questions based on the expected responses.

Comment: +1, the assistant seems a better solution if the questions are for configuration rather than some random quiz